# Should I delete FileHistory folder in D:/ after turning off File History service?

Tags: windows-10, file-history

Should I delete folder `D:\FileHistory` [>7GB] after turning off the File History service?

- `D:` only has 1.36GB of free space left, so I don't want to add software or large files to it

Comment: You could move `D:\FileHistory` to another partition/network share, versus shutting off the service entirely. If you want to fully disable it, but keep the file version backups `D:\FileHistory` contains, you could back it up to an external drive or create a WIM image of the folder, saving it to a backup location, which will drastically decrease the backup size: `Dism /Online /Capture-Image /ImageFile:"Z:\Backup\FileHistory.wim" /CaptureDir:"D:\FileHistory" /Name:"File History Backup" /Description:"File History for dates 2021.01.01 - 2022.03.07" /Compress:Max /CheckIntegrity /Verify`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to disable File History in
*Setting > Update & Security > Backup* and turn off
"Automatically back up my files".
Although in Advanced Settings there is a "Clean up versions" option,
it does not let you delete the last version.

To delete everything you need to go to the backup drive and delete
manually the
folder named `FileHistory`, where are stored all File History backup.
There is no problem in just deleting it.

Comment: ok thanks. I disabled the service